# I am trying to deploy two config server as replicaset using rs.initiate method but i am getting this error with my second config server while deploy

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops

```
"ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "replSetInitiate quorum check failed because not all proposed set members responded affirmatively: 172.31.10.124:27019 failed with Error connecting to 172.31.10.124:27019 :: caused by :: Connection refused",
    "code" : 74,
    "codeName" : "NodeNotFound",
    "$gleStats" : {
        "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
        "electionId" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000")
    },
    "lastCommittedOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0)
}
```

Comment: rs.initiate(
...    {
...       _id: "csr",
...       configsvr: true,
...       members: [
...          { _id: 0, host : "172.31.10.124:27019" },
...          { _id: 1, host : "172.31.5.240:27019" }
...       ]
...    }
... )

Comment: I am trying to setup mongodb sharded cluster with replicaset in aws.Above is my rs.intiate method that i used.

Comment: Did you start the services?

Comment: Please edit your question if you like to put additional information to the question instead of using comments.